# How to Connect ADLS Gen-1 with Azure ML Studio

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-machine-learning-service

Want to connect ADLS Gen-1 with AzureML Studio.

I try to find out some solution but could not get

Answer (score 1):

**Direct method:**

Currently, Azure Data Lake Store is not a supported source.

I would suggest you to vote up an idea submitted by another Azure customer.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake/suggestions/15008490-adl-store-connector-for-ml-studio

All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.

By using the Import Data module, you can access data from one of several online data sources while your experiment is running:

```
•   A Web URL using HTTP
•   Hadoop using HiveQL
•   Azure blob storage
•   Azure table
•   Azure SQL database or SQL Server on Azure VM
•   On-premises SQL Server database
•   A data feed provider, OData currently
•   Azure Cosmos DB
```

For more details, refer “[Supported data types in Azure ML studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio/import-data#supported-data-formats-and-data-types)”.

**In-direct method:**

Azure Data Lake Analytics can also be used to write data out to Azure Blob Store, and so you can use that as an approach to process the data in U-SQL and then stage it for Azure Machine Learning to process it from Blob store. When Azure ML supports Data Lake store, then you can switch that over.

For more details, refer "[How to use ADLS as an input data set for Azure ML Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36127510/how-to-use-azure-data-lake-store-as-an-input-data-set-for-azure-ml)".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I'll put my feedback on MS blog.